# Gradle Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Tags: android, gradle, proxy, android-gradle-plugin, jitpack

I can't build my android project due to this error. Gradle failed to GET https://www.jitpack.io/com/github/Raizlabs/DBFlow/dbflow/3.1.1/dbflow-3.1.1.pom . Strange enough I am able to view the pom file behind this URL in my browser. What might be the problem here?

My gradle.properties look like this:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=myproxy.local
systemProp.http.proxyPort=3210
systemProp.https.proxyHost=myproxy.local
systemProp.https.proxyPort=3210
systemProp.http.proxyUser=usr
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=pwd
```

When I remove the proxyUser/Password I get an 407 Proxy Authentication Required.

Answer (score 7):

For me this worked
1. Invalidate caches/restart
2. Sync project with gradle files

Answer (score 2):

Check the local 'gradle.properties'. My problem was on there. Somehow there was some proxy informations and they was wrong. I deleted it and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset android studio because we cannot get the sever response due to proxy matters.
Close Android Studio.
Please Go to C://Users/Username/. 
Then delete .gradle file and .Android Studio File.
After Open Android Studio and set settings.
I solved this problem using above steps.

Comment: The idea to look for .gradle folder gave me an idea to look into that folder for gradle.properties. Thank you) It helped me to solve my issue and I posted an answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy needs authentication and the authentication you supply is invalid or your proxy does not allow to request that URL with the authentication details you supply.

Comment: Proxy auth works.I wonder why I get an 403 Forbidden with gradle, sametime my browser can access the URL.

Comment: I guess your browser is configured differently. Either without proxy or with differing credentials I'd guess. Maybe install Wireshark and look at the network traffic to find the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You've only provided user/password for `systemProp.http`. You likely need to provide the same for `systemProp.https`

See [accessing the web via proxy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy)

Answer (score 0):

check gradle offline mode under settings and check local gradle then specify the path of you gradle.zip file its under

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but useful, i suppose. I realised that it is not allowed to read jitpack artifacts from a private repository without having a paid subscription:
https://jitpack.io/private

So that's might be a cause for `403` error.
You have an option either upgrade or make the repository public
Subscription must be bought for the repository's owner account.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a gradle.properties file in .gradle folder (on Mac it is in your home directory ~/.gradle/gradle.properties), check that for your proxy settings. That helped me. It is especially useful if your project level gradle.properties is shared with other developers via git.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading to Android X can fix the Forbidden! response problem.

- Open your project on Android Studio
- Top menu > Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX

- Don't forget backup your entire project before migrating.