# I Downloaded This File kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.pom But I don't know where i can save it

Tags: android

I installed Android Studio 4.1.2 and came across a Gradle sync error.
it says

> Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.72/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.pom'.
> Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

I downloaded this file: `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.pom`. But I don't know where I can save it.

Comment: I think you need to fix that 403 Forbidden Gradle error instead of downloading the file manually. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038496/gradle-received-status-code-403-from-server-forbidden)

Comment: Can you share your Gradle file?

Comment: thank you,,i solved my error by adding proxy setting in gradle properties(global properties) as .systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort= your port
systemProp.https.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem downloading that kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72

I realized that the problem was that I was using Charles Proxy, after close charles and run this command:

pkill -f '.*GradleDaemon.*'

i found that command here:

[I don't have a proxy, but Gradle says "Connect to 127.0.0.1:8888 [/127.0.0.1] failed", even after removing ~/.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63097744/i-dont-have-a-proxy-but-gradle-says-connect-to-127-0-0-18888-127-0-0-1-fa)

android studio was able to download that file.

thanks to aytek I realized was a proxy problem